# Trouble when deploying nodejs app to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

i'm trying to deploy my nodejs app to heroku an i've followed their documentation and went through the various steps as said. i entered the  heroku create, git push heroku master commands and no error message came up but when i head to the access link given to me, in returns this error:
**Method Not Allowed**. i'll do well to include my code sample
`*

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const _ = require('lodash');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://37888:commoncold@3788-j.1lyrm.mongodb.net/todolistDB');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
/* some code here*/
app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port ${PORT}");
});*
```

`

Comment: hey on line 9 you exposed your mongodb atlas password after BABA-J: password
you can store it in an environmental variable using `dotenv` etc.

Comment: i don't know if this could be the reason but i recently upgraded from the heroku-20 to heroku-22 stack and when i deployed my app and went back to my url, and it works!

Comment: thats cool but people can access your database if you don't edit it out or something just saying

Comment: oh thanks so much. i didn't even realize that.